# Names of properties

Tags: differences

I have the entity (abstraction) `Coupon`.
The coupon can be selected several times and used.
I need to record how many times the `Coupon` has been selected and used.

Please help to choose the names for these properties (it's for Java classes) which are most correct in English. (I'm not a native English speaker).

To record the number of times the coupon has been selected:

- timesSelected
- selectedTimes
- numberSelected
- selectedNumber
- selectedQuantity

To record the number of times the coupon has been used:

- timesUsed
- usedTimes
- numberUsed
- usedNumber
- usedQuantity

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things (especially programming constructs) is explicitly off-topic on EL&U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Variable:**

"To record the number of times the coupon has been selected:"

For the first one the best option would be `timesSelected`, since you are recording the number of times the coupon has been selected, not the number of coupons. This `timesSelected` is a contraction of 'number of times selected', which is itself a contraction of your first question statement.

`selectedTimes` is a reverse ordering, outside of the usual grammatical order in the English language. `numberSelected` would imply we were counting the number of coupons themselves, rather than the number of times they were selected (which may amount to the same thing, but it's not the *most* correct). `selectedNumber` would incorrectly imply you are selecting a number, which isn't really what you are trying to do. `selectedQuantity` would suggest an interest in the total quantity, which would refer to either the number selected, or a total quantity of tickets, which could prove confusing.

**Second Variable:**

"To record the number of times the coupon has been used:"

`timesUsed` would be the most correct. Again this is a contraction of the statement of intent you gave above the variables. The unit we want to measure is 'times the coupon is used,' which your variable name is a more brief form of...

Reasons the others don't work: Again, `usedTimes` is a reversal of the usual grammatical ordering, wherein the action to take effect is placed, counter-intuitively, after the action which it affects. Since we read left to right in English, the item would have to have been used before the times at which it was counted as having been used, which would seem to the casual observer to be impossible... `numberUsed` would be ok, but again we seem to be counting the number used, rather than the amount of times they are used, which could plausibly be different if there were unexpected nuances or details to the question. `usedNumber` has a combination of the problems listed for `usedTimes` and `numberUsed` and `usedQuantity` may also be confused with the quantity used, and not the number of times they've been used which, while, again, may well be the same, wouldn't necessarily be.

Hope those explanations help.